# Custom port in Systemd scrip

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to set a custom port in my Systemd script, here is my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=discord-stock-ticker
Wants=basic.target
After=basic.target network.target
Before=sshd.service

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=discord-stock-ticker
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStart=/opt/discord-stock-ticker/discord-stock-ticker -port 42069
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried a bunch of different option like `--PORT=xxx` or `--server.port=xxx`, but it still run 8080 port.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing the service file?  You need to in order to "commit" the changes so to speak.

Comment: Yes, but I just receive one more `discord-stock-ticker.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.` message in `systemctl status discord-stock-ticker.service`

Comment: So what's the flag that's supposed to be passed to `discord-stock-ticker` to specify the port it's supposed to listen on?  It looks like you're just trying random options that may not even exist for that binary.

Another option you can do is run another service that forwards port 8080 to 42069

Comment: Oh, I see now, I thought that there is a universal flag for all binaries. Thank you!